# Best practise when loading foreign assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I'm looking for some guidance on how best to treat foreign assemblies as part of a distribution and loading.

The basics is, I've been working on a program that is designed to interact with another installed program.
The other program has open .Net API's designed for interfacing with third party applications like my own, however it is updated quite regularly.
The changes aren't always breaking changes, but this generally forces me to update my own application and cut a release for the public.

The three main concepts I've considered are:

1. Package the foreign assemblies that contains only the APIs with my own application. 
   Considered cons are: increased distro size. Forcing checks between the binaries of the installed foreign application and the local copy of the API binaries, and attempting to update them to remain in sync.
2. Load the foreign assemblies directly from where they exist in the foreign install folder.
   Considered cons are: locking the binaries if the foreign app decides to update them.
3. Copy the foreign assemblies to a temporary folder, and load them from there.
   Considered cons are: time taken to copy dozens of files (which include resource assemblies), and potentially leave them in the temporary folder.

Is there a best practise, or another recognised way of doing this?

EDIT: I should point out that my application uses WPF.

Comment: Shadow Copying Assemblies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've just had a close look at the AppDomainSetup.ShadowCopyDirectories, and I'm not sure that this is suited for *two* sets of assemblies from separate locations. The local referenced assemblies and the foreign assemblies both need to be loaded by the application. And AppDomainSetup appears to work with only one group. I had to manually load the locally referenced assemblies lest a File Not Found Exception be thrown.

Comment: Have you considered using [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx) resp. [PRISM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx)? It is created for exactly such tasks as in your case. Quote from MSDN: `Why We Built It

Several years ago, within Microsoft, a number of groups were working to find solutions to a problem—how to build applications from reusable components that can be discovered, reused and composed dynamically`.

Answer (score 0):

Some general concepts I follow when working with third party applications:

- Put an [Adapter Layer](http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html) between the third party API and your code to provide an interface between your objects and the third party objects. Breaking changes will be altered in your Adapter Layer to make it compatible.
- Use stubs for the external services in tests so you can switch out the third party calls

You could consider the idea of a following the "Border Guard" methodology, mentioned on a [Dan North Accelerated Agile](http://dannorth.net/) course I attended. In this strategy, you pair up with the third party API in advance of them making breaking changes. Write a suite of unit tests for the system that describe your use of them, and the third party then integrates them into their own system unit tests. You are then informed of any breaking changes to your system with their API updates before they push them upstream! If this is something you could work with the third party to do it could save some future pain.